# pyttsx3 module is not giving any output

Tags: python, pyttsx3

I'm having some troubles with the pyttsx3 module. At first I couldn't even initialize it and I got this error:

```
File "/home/emanuele/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyttsx3/__init__.py", line 20, in init
eng = _activeEngines[driverName]
File "/usr/lib/python3.9/weakref.py", line 137, in __getitem__
o = self.data[key]()
KeyError: None

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/emanuele/AllInOneApp.py", line 3, in <module>
engine = pyttsx3.init()
File "/home/emanuele/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyttsx3/__init__.py", line 22, in init
eng = Engine(driverName, debug)
File "/home/emanuele/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyttsx3/engine.py", line 30, in __init__
self.proxy = driver.DriverProxy(weakref.proxy(self), driverName, debug)
File "/home/emanuele/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyttsx3/driver.py", line 50, in __init__
self._module = importlib.import_module(name)
File "/usr/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 850, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "/home/emanuele/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyttsx3/drivers/espeak.py", line 3, in <module>
import ctypes
File "/usr/lib/python3.9/ctypes/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ImportError: libffi.so.8: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Then I solved it by running this two commands

```
pip uninstall pyttsx3
```

and

```
pip install pyttsx3==2.71
```

and adding to the init function the argument 'dummy'.
The problem is that now it runs without errors, but I don't get any output from the module

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the solution. Refer below for the fix.

**Run:** `sudo apt install libespeak1`

**Explanation:** `libspeak1` package is needed for running `pyttsx3` in ubuntu.